# Async Validation WCF RIA Services - Domain Context Exception

Tags: c#, wcf-ria-services, customvalidator

I have  custom validation to verify if a username already exists, it works fine on the client, i.e. type in an existing username and I see a validation error message. When I hit submit, I get an error message saying that the DomainContext is not initialized.

Using a domain service factory (Global.asax.cs) to create a domain service and adding the user as a parameter to the domain service constructor. This seems to be cause of the error.

In the custom validation (refernce: http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2010/05/26/asyncvalidation-again.aspx) the domain context piece of code which invokes the method works fine from the client but the domain service needs a user, so I used the following: "new AuthenticationService().GetUser()" to retreive user; which does not work since the FormsAuthentication GetUser method gives me an error message saying that DomainContext is not initialized.

Not sure if this is correct but I tried to create DomainServiceContext using the Authentication as the ServiceProvider but that gives me an error saying System.ServiceModel assembly not reference when I can clearly see that its referenced.

Does anyone have any thoughts of how to resolve this issue?
Thanks.